# eigen vectors and non-linear transformation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is this possible to have eigen vectors in non-linear transformation ? i knew eigen vectors were those vectors that doesnot change its span after transformation . how  to visualize it in quadratic transformation

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_eigenproblem.